# Renaming node with namespace

Tags: xml, xquery

Hi I have an issue with namespaces

My XML is as follows:

```
<earnings xmlns="http://www.dppvgu.com" currency="USD">
  <distribution>15002111</distribution>
  <ticket_sales>
    <distribution num="2">24450144</distribution>
    <distribution num="3">12057133</distribution>
  </ticket_sales>
  <digital_sales>
    <ppv_sales>19220907</ppv_sales>
    <stream_sales>49725265</stream_sales>
    <disc_sales>15082021</disc_sales>
  </digital_sales>
</earnings>
```

I would like to rename the node `<distribution>15002111</distribution>`  using the following command:

```
for $doc in doc("earnings.xml")/*[local-name() = 'earnings']/*[local-name() = 'distribution']
return rename node $doc as 'postbox'
```

I get the following error: `[XUDY0023] Conflicts with existing namespaces.`

How do I resolve the issue? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `QName()` to specify the new name to be in the default namespace :

```
for $doc in doc("earnings.xml")/*[local-name() = 'earnings']/*[local-name() = 'distribution']
return rename node $doc as QName('http://www.dppvgu.com','postbox')
```

or using `QName()` in combination with `namespace-uri()` to avoid hardcoding the namespace :

```
for $doc in doc("earnings.xml")/*[local-name() = 'earnings']/*[local-name() = 'distribution']
return rename node $doc as QName(namespace-uri($doc),'postbox')
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks.
But what if I have multiple `earnings` in the xml file with different namespaces?

Comment: @DhirajEadara In that case, you can replace the hardcoded namespace with `namespace-uri($doc)`